# Flutter : how to use focusNode property on TextField

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to control the `TextField` widget when f user taps on it. How can I implement the `focusNode` property? There's no detailed explanation in the description.

Comment: What exactly is the question. " how can i implement this focusNode property" is quite vague.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
FocusNode focusNode;

void initState() {
  focusNode = new FocusNode();

  // listen to focus changes
  focusNode.addListener(() => print('focusNode updated: hasFocus: ${focusNode.hasFocus}')); 
}

void setFocus() {
  FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(focusNode);
}

Widget build() {
  return
  ...
  new TextField(focusNode: focusNode, ...);
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Don't forget to dispose of it afterwards to avoid memory leaks:

```
@override
  void dispose() {
    focusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

How to Focus Control from outside tapped or pressed;

```
FocusNode emailFocus = FocusNode();
FocusNode passFocus = FocusNode();
```

//Add GestureDetector for getting outside touch event;

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    try {
      emailFocus.unfocus();
      passFocus.unfocus();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }

    print("Tapped");
  },
```

//add focus in textfield

```
 TextFormField(
                    autofocus: true,
                    focusNode: passFocus,
```